# Are there any disadvantages to running a function in react hook useState's set parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I had a situation when I had to use the current values for further processing and couldn't rely on dependencies to update the function in time. I had to do something similar to the following.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({});
const someCallback = useCallback(() => {
  setValues((values) => {
    if(values.x === 'something') return ({ ...values, x: 'something else' });
    return values;
  });
}, []);
```

It works for me but that doesn't mean its right. I've never seen anyone use it like above but I can't see anything wrong with above. Are there any disadvantages to using the useState's set parameter like this?

Comment: *"...and couldn't rely on dependencies to update the function in time..."* Why not?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Had a similar callback that made multiple changes to values. Callback would 'refresh' every time values changed since values was a dependency and the callback was connected to a useEffect, causing useEffect to run creating side effects. This looked like the best solution without disabling eslint hook rules and just removing the values from the dependency array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see any problem with it. You've declared that there are no dependencies, which is correct because you're using the callback version of `setValues` (and `setValues`, itself, is guaranteed to be stable).

The one *minor* thing I might do, which is more of a style thing and could be argued both ways, is I'd probably use a different name for the `values` parameter of the `setValues` callback, for clarity:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({});
const someCallback = useCallback(() => {
  setValues((currentValues) => {
    if(currentValues.x === 'something') return ({ ...currentValues, x: 'something else' });
    return currentValues;
  });
}, []);
```

But again, what you have seems fine.

Comment: *(The premature micro-optimizer in me chafes at the fact that every render after the first one will create a function it doesn't need or use, and suggests moving the function out of the component and passing `setValues` to it as a parameter. But I'm usually able to beat him into submission.)*